# Is there a method to approximate indefinite integrals?

Tags: reference-request, indefinite-integrals

i am aware of various numerical methods for solving definite integrals like Gauss Quadrature rule, Traezoidal rule, Simpson rules etc. But I could not find any such numerical methods for approximating indefinite integrals.

You know, like a process or formula, if you plug in the function, it'll approximate the indefinite integral, in terms of series or something idk, but it will give it in terms of x.
It seems odd that since Newton no one found a way to do that, it's like 500 years or so, there must be something.

Comment: This does exist.

Comment: what is the method then?

Comment: The solution to the indefinite integral $\int f(x) \: dx$ can be written as $F(x)+C$, where $F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) \: dt$ for some fixed $a$. And thus any method of approximating the definite integral $\int_a^x f(t) \: dt$ will also give a way of approximating $\int f(x) \: dx$.